# Consolidated queue for video on demand?

Tags: itunes, netflix, front-row

It's great having lots of video on demand options, but actually choosing something to watch is turning into a mess - I have to jump from one website or application to another.

I'd like to have a single queue where I can add and prioritize movies and TV I want to watch from any source: iTunes purchases, iTunes rentals, Netflix on demand, Amazon video on demand, Hulu, etc.

I'd like the consolidated queue to be accessible from Front Row on my Mac Mini.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

Most of these sources have a vested interest in preventing you from accessing them outside their DRM protected interfaces. It's pretty unlikely that you'll find one tool for using them all. Hulu, for example, worked on the Boxee app for a while, but Hulu shut it down at the behest of the media companies.

Comment: I don't agree - I don't think DRM is the issue. FrontRow is able to play iTunes video as well as Netflix and Hulu (using the Understudy plugin). I'm guessing it would be possible to make a plugin that provides a seamless interface for all of these.